# Tensorflow model.evaluate gives different result from that obtained from training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using tensorflow to do a multi-class classification

I load the training dataset and validation dataset in the following way

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  shuffle=True,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  shuffle=True,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Then when I train the model using model.fit()

```
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs,
  shuffle=True
)
```

I get validation accuracy around 95%.

But when I load the same validation set and use model.evaluate()

```
model.evaluate(val_ds)
```

I get very low accuracy (around 10%).

Why am I getting such different results? Am I using the model.evaluate function incorrectly?

Note : In the model.compile() I am specifying the following,
Optimizer - Adam,
Loss - SparseCategoricalCrossentropy,
Metric - Accuracy

Model.evaluate() output

```
41/41 [==============================] - 5s 118ms/step - loss: 0.3037 - accuracy: 0.1032
Test Loss -  0.3036555051803589
Test Acc -  0.10315627604722977
```

Model.fit() output for last three epochs

```
Epoch 8/10
41/41 [==============================] - 3s 80ms/step - loss: 0.6094 - accuracy: 0.8861 - val_loss: 0.4489 - val_accuracy: 0.9483
Epoch 9/10
41/41 [==============================] - 3s 80ms/step - loss: 0.5377 - accuracy: 0.8953 - val_loss: 0.3868 - val_accuracy: 0.9554
Epoch 10/10
41/41 [==============================] - 3s 80ms/step - loss: 0.4663 - accuracy: 0.9092 - val_loss: 0.3404 - val_accuracy: 0.9590
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your model as `.h5` instead of `.tf` - this worked for me in Keras 2.4.0 and tensorflow 2.4.0

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting such different results? Am I using the model.evaluate
> function incorrectly?

I suppose that it is the over fitting that cause this issue. You can check them out in this way!

---

1. **Extract the history of model**

   ```
   history_dict = history.history
   history_dict.keys()
   ```
2. **Visualize the history**

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
   acc=history_dict['accuracy']
   val_acc=history_dict['val_accuracy']
   loss=history_dict['loss']
   val_loss=history_dict['val_loss']

   epochs=range(1,len(acc)+1)    
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

   ax1=plt.subplot(221)
   ax1.plot(epochs,loss,'bo',label='Training loss')
   ax1.plot(epochs,acc,'ro',label='Training acc')
   ax1.set_title('loss and acc of Training')
   ax1.set_xlabel('Epochs')
   ax1.set_ylabel('Loss')
   ax1.legend()

   ax2=plt.subplot(222)
   ax2.plot(epochs,val_acc,'r',label='Validation acc')
   ax2.plot(epochs,val_loss,'b',label='Validation loss')
   ax2.set_title('loss and acc of Training')
   ax2.set_xlabel('Epochs')
   ax2.set_ylabel('Acc')
   ax2.legend()
   ```

---

**Maybe, the results you get are like these:**

- In training process, acc and loss changed with epochs
- But in validation, acc and loss seem to reached a peak after 20 epochs

**Solution**

It turns out that, when overfitting occurs, fewer epochs can be set to avoid this problem!